# Unpredictable need for Platform.runLater

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, exception, javafx, task

In a JavaFX application I have a TabPane with about a dozen tabs. Based on the users element selection in a ListView, the complete dataset for this selected element is pulled from a database and each tab will show a certain type of information. Most often the type of information per tab consists of Strings, Integers and alike but several tabs show also the development of numerical data over time in different charts. In order to gain performance I created for each tab a dedicated Task/Thread. This was generating dozens of "Not on FX application thread exceptions" what I expected. Since updateProgress is not sufficient for the UI update of each tab, I started to enclose code that updates the tab UI and throws the exception with Platform.runLater. Once all UI code was wrapped everything looked fine and the nice thing was that each Platform.runLater was just covering a few lines of code. About right to stick to the concept of running only short tasks in Platform.runLater.

If I run the application with the same test data, it works in 75% of the cases reproducible. But every now and then, code that worked in all these previous runs  fine, throws the "Not on FX application thread" exception. When checking the causing source code, it is correct, that this code should have been wrapped in a Platform.runLater from the beginning on.

My question is: How comes that the code sometimes throws the exception and sometimes not, using the same test data? I would expect that the exception is thrown always. It feels a little unpredictable.

Comment: In later versions of JavaFX those exceptions where often removed and therefore code may just fail silently or with cryptic exceptions during layout, but some parts are probably still in there. Nowadays you cannot rely on this kind of exceptions. My suspicion here is that in some cases the skin of a control throws the exception and this doesn't happen, if the skin hasn't been initialized which happens during the first layout pass...

Comment: if you know the update happens off the ui thread, you know that you are doing something wrong, irrespective of an exception being thrown or not, don't you ;) Don't ever to make sure you are safe. That said: @fabian nailed it, many exceptions where removed (don't know why) - what remained are modifications to the scenegraph: when children are added/removed to/from the scenegraph and this results in a layout pass, the exception is still thrown - but also unreliable as long as the parent isn't yet added to the scenegraph.